# Python cron job file access

Tags: python, linux, file-io, cron

I have a tiny Python script that needs to read/write to a file. It works when I run it from the command line (since I am root, it will) , but when the cron job runs it cannot access the file.

The file is in the same folder as the script and is (should) be created from the script.

I'm not sure if this is really a programming question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use absolute path in your script when using crontab to run it

Answer (score 3):

in addition to the 1st answer, you could use the following code:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_name = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'filename.dat')
```

Comment: Thi is much better as its portable. The first line finds your directory, so if you run "python /home/user/TEST/test.py" as your cron job, it will return /home/user/TEST. You can then join them up, using the second line